# change \crefname for appendix in document

Tags: appendices, cleveref

I want to change how an appendix section is referred to for part of my document:
I want "appendix A.1" in the main text and "section A.1" in the appendix.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    \cref{foo} and \cref{bar}

    \appendix
    \crefname{subappendix}{section}{sections}

    \section{Foo}\label{foo}
    \cref{foo} and \cref{bar}

    \subsection{Bar}\label{bar}
\end{document}
```

I expected an output like:

> appendix A and appendix A.1
>
> A Foo
>
> appendix A and *section A.1*
>
> A.1 Bar

But I also get "appendix A.1" within the appendix.

It seems like I can only use `\crefname` in the preamble and affect the whole document.
Is there a way to change the the reference name only for the appendix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apptools` package introduces relevant conditionals `\IfAppendix` and `\ifappendix`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{apptools}
\crefname{subappendix}{\IfAppendix{section}{appendix}}{\IfAppendix{sections}{appendices}s}

\begin{document}
    \cref{foo} and \cref{bar}

    \appendix

    \section{Foo}\label{foo}
    \cref{foo} and \cref{bar}

    \subsection{Bar}\label{bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]